# Subscriptions and unsubscriptions do not affect client working in another process

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I have 2 services - one suscribes/unsubscribes on some channels, anther one handles pushes. I seems that these subscriptions made by the first client in the first process don't affect the second one - it doesn't receive pushes from added channels. At least immediately (I waited for 20 mins). After process restart it started working well.
Is it 100% procent neccessary to reinitialize client in my scenario or there is some way to avoid it?

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: hi Denis, please provide some code

Comment: Hi Ali. The code I use is 100% working in one process scenario - I subscribe on channel and immediately able to get pushes by the same WTelegramClient object. But If I subscribe on Telegram pushes via OnUpdate event in one process, then suscribe on some channel using JoinChannel in another - I don't get pushes from that channel in the first process. So I'm wondering - is it by design or may be some workaround exists...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.